# Integer subtraction and looping based on integer values

Tags: vb.net, console-application, subtraction, basic

I'm having two problems here. First off all I want to x to change values to x - y and if the new X is higher then 0 i want the process to repeat itself. I've worked out the code below but i'm not certiant on two things.

1. Am I even allowed to make the equation x = x - y or does this mess up everything? I mean in mathematical terms it would not be possible but if we take X as Hp and Y as damage I want the damage to add up. I don't want it to create an "damage HP" integer for every subtraction as I even don't know how many "Z = x - y" style equations I would have to create if I set Y to be random.
   My guess is that I could create a Z integral that would copy X a moment before the subtraction would go off and then have the subtraction be X = Z - Y but I'm not sure how I would go about coding this.
2. I want it to go ahead and loop itself if X is higher then 0 and I'm not sure if I coded that correctly.

Here is my code:

```
Module Module1
        Dim A As Integer
        Dim B As Integer
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
        Sub Main()

    End Sub

    Sub Maths()
        A = 5
        B = 4
        x = 3
        y = 1
        Subtraction()
        Console.WriteLine("You deal {0} damage to your enemy reducing it to {1} hp.", y, x)
            Do Until x <= 0

            Loop
    End Sub
    Private Sub Subtraction()
        If A > B Then x = x -y
            Return
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked this question. Here's my thoughts:

1. Yes, `x = x - y` is perfectly valid code. It's no different than if I had a string variable named `myRunOnSentence` and I wanted to concatenate the string that was already in the variable and another string and then store the results back in the string variable. Like this: `myRunOnSentence = myRunOnSentence + "another string"` Same concept, just change the datatype to an Integer. `x = x + y`. That programatically says: "take the value in x and the value in y, add them together, and store the result of that expression in x."
2. You did indeed make a mistake with the loop. You don't have any code inside the body of the loop itself.
3. You have nothing happening in the `Main()` sub of your module so this module when run will do nothing. You should just take the code from the `Maths()` method and put it in the `Main()` sub.
4. In your `Subtraction()` method, `A > B` will always evaluate to `True` because `A` and `B` are initialized with values and then never changed.

Your code should look something like this:

```
Module Module1
    Dim A As Integer = 5
    Dim B As Integer = 4
    Dim x As Integer = 3
    Dim y As Integer = 1

    Sub Main()
        Do Until x <= 0
            Subtraction()
            Console.WriteLine("You deal {0} damage to your enemy reducing it to {1} hp.", y, x)
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub Subtraction()
        If A > B Then x = x - y 'Return statement wasn't needed.
    End Sub
End Module
```

If this answered your question, please don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help:)
I've completely missed the fact that I didn't put anything in main (in my defence it was 1 am). I know that A will always be bigger then B as this is just a mockup of another project where I use RNG to determine A and B. Thank you for clearing things up ^^

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.